# General Liability amounts for a home podcast

Tags: liability

We have a small in home podcast that we do weekly.  How much general liability should we have to "cover" it as a business?

Comment: Do you have an LLC or personally exposed? Do you have guests in your home for the podcast? Is the podcast giving out financial, medical, or legal advice?

Comment: How can your podcast harm others?

Comment: Is the podcast controversial in any way?  Could you possibly accused of slander some day?  Absent possible risks like this and in the above comments, you probably don't need business insurance.

Comment: It’s a Star Wars podcast